# Get POST Content from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, http, post, servlets

I want to read out the data from a **POST** request in a **Java Servlet**. This servlet runs on the Geoserver as service and called with the URL.

---

**POST Request (create with python script):**

```
POST http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?request=upload&service=GeoTransfer&version=1.0.0 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: python-requests/2.20.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: application/xml
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: admin:admin
fileName: transfer.xml
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 489

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<transfer>
  <enviroment>Test</enviroment>
  <product>Testproduct</product>
  <user>admin</user>
</transfer>
```

---

**Java servlet:**

```
public void upload(HttpServletRequest request, httpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("===== Begin headers =====");
        Enumeration<String> names = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerName = names.nextElement();
            System.out.println(headerName + " = " + request.getHeader(headerName));
        }
        System.out.println("===== End headers =====\n");


        System.out.println("===== Begin Body =====");
        if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {

            try {
                Scanner s = new Scanner(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A");
                System.out.println(s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("===== End Body =====\n");

 }
```

---

**Output:**

```
===== Begin headers =====
Authorization = admin:admin
fileName = transfer.xml
Accept = application/xml
User-Agent = python-requests/2.20.0
Connection = keep-alive
Host = localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding = gzip, deflate
Content-Length = 489
Content-Type = application/xml
===== End headers =====

===== Begin Body =====

===== End Body =====
```

---

**Problem:**

Why i cant read out the xml data body? 
Is something wrong with the request and the data dont pass to Java?

**EDIT1:**

Try other Methods with Inputstream, but the body is always a empty line.
Could be the Problem that the Server ignore the Body and use only the header if he create the request object ?

**Edit2:**

Try Majid Khakwani answer and get empty string. 
I print out `request.getContentLength()` and it is `489`. Did the method get this number out of the header or the real length of the content from object request?

Comment: I think you should use `while(s.hasNext()) { System.out.println(s.next()); } `

Comment: Nothing...i think the body dont exist at my request in java because i get false if i check for a line. But why it exist in my Post and at my Server i get only the Header

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                String xml = null;
                try {
                        byte[] xmlData = new byte[request.getContentLength()];

                        //Start reading XML Request as a Stream of Bytes
                        InputStream sis = request.getInputStream();
                        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(sis);

                        bis.read(xmlData, 0, xmlData.length);

                        if (request.getCharacterEncoding() != null) {
                                xml = new String(xmlData, request.getCharacterEncoding());
                        } else {
                                xml = new String(xmlData);
                        }
                        //xml and xmlData contains incomplete data
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                   ...
                }
```